# AS3 - Manually created MovieClips and 'Convert into compiled clip' trouble

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to use compiled clips to speed up compilation.

But I've found following problem:

I've got Foo class, which `extends MovieClip` and is set as 'Class' to one of library's symbol (this symbol is also called Foo).

This symbol (Foo) has a MovieClip child, whose instance name is `FOO_CHILD`. I'm referencing this child inside `Foo` class constructor like this:

`public function Foo(){

    childReferennce = this.getChildByName("FOO_CHILD");

}`

Now, when I use 'Convert into compiled clip' option on Foo library symbol it complies fine. But when I try to use it on stage, then I've got runtime error (`ReferenceError: Error #1056` which says that it is not able to create "FOO_CHILD" property on my Foo class).

**How to do that correctly?**

Answer (score 1):

Make the class dynamic. ie:

```
package {
    dynamic public class Foo {
        // class code here
    }
}
```